# Object duplicates cause lag

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I have a really strange issue happening in Blender. I have some simple low poly objects where I'm trying to build some RTS style buildings. The walls of my buildings are just some simple planes with a texture on top of them. If I duplicate them, for some reason it slows down my entire blender really hard, that you can't even use it anymore. Camera rotation or zooming in lags really hard. I thought at first that maybe it's a poly issue so I deleted my plane copies and then just created a bunch of monkey heads to see if I'd get the same thing and nothing. I then copied the material from one of my other objects to the monkey heads and applied the same texture atlas and still no issues. So 4-5 copies of a simple plane that has a texture on it makes my Blender lag, but 4-5 copies of monkey heads using the same texture does not. I'm using the Blender Renderer with Texture View.

Any thoughts on what could be going on?
Thanks!

P.S. - I also thought that maybe it's due to having too many groups. All the duplicates would create a new group. Still didn't help.

Comment: If there are any modifiers on the plane, this definitely sounds weird. How big is your blend file? Consider uploading to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and posting the given link in your question.

Comment: It's pretty small, 1.9mb. No modifiers either. The whole thing is just a bunch of planes that are placed together to resemble building walls and roofs.

Comment: How many objects are there in the scene after duplicating planes ?

Comment: Well a house is formed out of something like 8-10 objects (4 planes for the walls, 2 for roof etc...), but I really doubt that's the issue as I already tested for that and I have other files that have a whole lot more objects and don't have any issues..

Comment: I did one more test though and this might help. After I duplicated the objects again and it got really laggy, I took each one of them, pressed tab to enter edit mode and in my UV Editor I deleted the background image so they all now appear white.. note that I'm in "Texture View" in my scene view and that the materials and texture remained the same... so it looks like it might be an issue regarding the texture in the UV editor because as soon as I deleted them, things went back to normal, no longer being laggy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. It was the size of the texture. I was using a large texture atlas and that was its limit. I did a test where I shrunk the atlas to 1/4th and I no longer have that issue. I can use a smaller texture atlas for modeling and then use the original texture when I import it into the game.